# Turning sql to jpql in javafx

Tags: jquery, sql, netbeans, jpql

Im trying to do a query for a javafx project and I need the sql code converted to jpql in order for it to work. When trying to load up my ServerSide with the query in the code, it doesnt work, wether its the sql code or the jpql code i tried.

When i put the query under comments, everything works fine so it most probably is the query

This is the sql code

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Pokemon.findPokemonByUserId", query = 
            "SELECT p FROM pokemon p "
                    + "JOIN p.favourites f "
                    + "JOIN f.user u "
                    + "WHERE u.idUser = :idUser")
```

And this is the jpql code i tried but it doesnt work

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Pokemon.findPokemonByUserId", query = 
            "SELECT p FROM  pokemon JOIN favourites f ON idPokemon = pokemon_idPokemon " + 
            "JOIN user u ON idUser = user_idUser " + 
            "WHERE idUser = :idUser;")
```